# Hive Server in Cloudera quickstart

Tags: hadoop, servlets, jdbc, hive, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to create a form and using servlets connect with hive´s tables. But I have some doubts:

- Is Hive server installed in cloudera quickstart?
- It is necessary other server like Tomcat for the servlet?
- Must I have the libraries in the IDE? Or also in other place?
- Is possible with a form launch a servlet and display the data in the navigator on cloudera quickstart?
- JDBC must be installed in my local host or also in the virtual machine?
- Where do I declare the XML?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using HiveServer JDBC, 
Write your web application and deploy where ever you want to just use Hive JDBC drivers to connect and query Hive.

Here is more info Hive JDBC 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

Comment: You linked to the original HiveServer client. The new documentation for HiveServer2 is here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC

Comment: which server is installed in quickstart? hive or hive2?  JDBC must be installed in my local host or also in the virtual machine?   Where do I declare the XML?